# How to use xstream to convert xml string into SparseArray object?

Tags: xml, sparse-matrix, xstream

I know how to use xStream to convert xml into a object, which may contain a array type field or vector. But I have no idea whether I could use it to convert into a SparseArray. Here is a demo code:

Say I have a school, and a school have many classrooms, each classroom has a room number. Very simple mode. And good to use a sparseArray.

```
public class School {
    private SparseArray<Classroom> classrooms;
}

public class Classroom {
    private roomNumber;
    //OtherStuff
}
```

Now I have a xml file like this:

```
<school>
    <class>
        <room_number>1</room_number>
        <student_number>100</student_number>
    </class>
    <class>
        <room_number>2</room_number>
        <student_number>100</student_number>
    </class>
</school>
```

If I have the string of this xml file. How can I setup xStream to convert it into my School class? with correct key set into the sparsearray of it?

Thank you!

Added: Any other approach not using xStream is also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

XStream works with Converters. For some "classical" object-types such as ArrayList, HashMap, ... XStream has a bunch of predefined Converters.
Your SparseArray is no java "classical" object and XStream does not have a build-in Converter.

So, I would suggest you to build your own based on XStream's ArrayConverter (located in `com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.ArrayConverter`). This class is pretty straightforward and it should not be a difficult task.